# how to maintain settings across different repositories

Tags: git, settings

So I have `.eslint` and `.settings` (VSCode) files that I would like to be consistent across projects. How would I do this?

Currently, I am thinking that I should put them into a repository, which then I would instantiate as a submodule in new projects, which then I can symlink to.

Answer (score 1):

Since your development settings have little to do with the source of your actual projects, I would suggest actually separating them into different repos, while keeping their source in the same directory on your dev machine.

And since this could be achieved using git submodules, I do not see a reason not to use these. I mean, that seems as exactly the use-case they were made for.